# My speakers and headphones are not working on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: audio, ubuntu, alsa, ubuntu-12.10, pulseaudio

I used to work on Ubuntu 12.10 but then suddenly my speakers stopped working, my headphones didn't used to work before and still they are not working, i then upgraded to 13.04 in hope that it may solve my problem, but it was not the case. I have read dozens of websites and suggestion and tried them out, but none worked. As i open my sound configurations the only option available there is "Play sound through Dummy output" and i am unable to change that. Please help me out.
P.S I have my ubuntu dual booted with windows 7. And the speakers and headphones work fine on windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install alsa drivers from alsa launchpad.. be sure to install the latest version and that too of raring as you are using 13.04. After install try rebooting the laptop. This will make the sound work.